# How to render (bitmap) only part of a Visual?

Tags: wpf

I must print a displayed TreeView.

Rendering the root TreeViewItem to bitmap, gives me an image of the whole (even non visible nodes) tree. Then I split the bitmap in "pages" to be printed. The rendering code:

```
m_Bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)l_RootTreeViewItem.ActualHeightDesiredSize.Width,
                                  (int)l_RootTreeViewItem.ActualHeight, 96, 96,
                                  PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

m_Bitmap.Render(l_RootTreeViewItem);
```

Works well for small size trees. If the tree is large, **RenderTargetBitmap** results in **"Out Of Memory"** Exception.

So, the idea is to render only parts of the visual to avoid memory problems. A **Render** method where I can choose which part of visual to render will be perfect...

```
m_Bitmap.Render(l_RootTreeViewItem, xOffset, yOffset, width, height);
```

... but doesn't exist. Is there some way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'll do :

- Create a `VisualBrush` of your `l_RootTreeViewItem`
- Create a `Rectangle` and assign the visual brush to the `Fill` property
- Play with `VisualBrush.Viewbox` and `VisualBrush.Viewport` to render the part of the tree view I'm interested in
- Use `RenderTargetBitmap.Render` on my rectangle when needed

**EDIT**

Solution 2

- Put `l_RootTreeViewItem` in a canvas
- Set the `ClipToBounds` property of the canvas to true
- Play with `Canvas.Width`, `Canvas.Height` properties and `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top` attached properties to display only a part of the `TreeViewItem`
- Use `PrintDialog.PrintVisual` on the canvas as needed.

  ```
  <Canvas Width="300" Height="300" ClipToBounds="True">
      <TreeViewItem Canvas.Left="-200" Canvas.Top="-100">
          ...
      </TreeViewItem>
  </Canvas>
  ```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, your method works. Now I have a lot of RenderTargetBitmap.Render calls and the printing is slow, but is another problem (we need hardware accelerated rendering).

Comment: Do you know that you can print a visual directly? It's faster and looks better as it's vector printing (and not bitmap printing).

Comment: In the current case I must use a non-WPF report library and use bitmaps. Are you talking about WPF (WPS) documents?

Comment: Take a look at `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.PrintVisual`. It takes a Visual and print it. You can skip the `RenderTargetBitmap` pass and submit your 'rectangle' directly. Trust me, you gonna see the difference in speed and quality.

Comment: Yeap! Fast and nice. I feel the pagination will not be easy, but I will try. Thanks.

Comment: Well... printing (one page, no pagination) of the "original" visual takes 2 sec. but printing of rectangle filled with VisualBrush takes more than 1 minute... WPF can be frustrating.

Comment: Solution 2: In my specific case, as my TreeView is displayed, I can't add the TreeViewItem to the Canvas (already a parent). But can be usefull in other cases (to be tested). Thanks.